# How to conditionally update the value of an object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am learning Python and working on a sequencing program
In the program I have an attribut called 'Uptime'

Uptime has a fixed value of 60mins (for each day)
I want to create a function that will conditionnally Update the 'Uptime'

To drive more clarity, I use an excel to retrieve the Uptime value:

`Uptime_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Up_value')`

And here is the function I tried to create in order to not use a fixed value, but rather a value that will change accordingly to another attribut called 'Day':

```
def get_uptime_value(Uptime_data, day : Day, week : Week):
        if day[Week] == 7: 
            Uptime_data += 120
            return Uptime_data
```

The function itself has no error, but nothing changes in the Program.
Can you please help and spot what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks !

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make ure to show the code exactly as you actually have it, indentation and all. Please also read [ask] and [mre], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We aren't interested in your level of skill, or your thanks; and we [do not offer "help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), nor a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service. We *do* answer clear, explicit, specific questions (one per post).

Comment: the function has many errors. for a start `Day` and `Week` are not defined types. secondly the `Week` inside the `if statement` should be lower case. . .  but in any event to run the code, you need to call the function. finally, what are you trying to achieve ?